# Find a Matching HTML tag in Coda for Mac OS X

Tags: html, ide, tags, syntax-highlighting, coda

I've been doing web development in Coda recently. It's a really fantastic app, however there are some very annoying quirks. When going through a list of 5 or 6 closing divs I'm trying to find the quickest way to match up the closing tag with it's partner.

Some other IDEs will highlight the brackets<>, others will display a line highlighter. I don't know if there's any way to enable a similar feature in Coda? I'm having to match up the indentations and check myself with Chrome Inspecter, which is a huge pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one feature Coda does not support. Other IDEs have had it forever, Dreamweaver comes to mind first. You can request the feature by emailing the guys over at Panic. They are VERY responsive to user requests in future updates. Their address is coda@panic.com.

Otherwise, you can quickly copy paste the text over to [TextWrangler](http://pine.barebones.com/freeware/TextWrangler_3.5.3.dmg) (which does support the feature) and make sure all the tags are in order before uploading. I use it as my main HTML/PHP IDE. It's great for webdevs.

Comment: awesome man, straight to the point I like it! Yeah strange.. I'll shoot them an e-mail just to see what their thoughts are. Also downloading TextWrangler now I appreciate the direct link :)

Answer (score 5):

Try the [Zen Coding Plugin for Coda](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/).

**Edit:**

Zen Coding has been [renamed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_Coding): It is now called Emmet. There is an up-to-date [Emmet plugin for Coda](https://github.com/emmetio/Emmet.codaplugin) on GitHub.

There are various options available in the Plug-ins > Emmet menu, but the quick-and-dirty way to match a start and end tag is to place your cursor within the tag of interest and use the following key combination: <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: The Zen Coding Plugin for Coda is not supported and only works on Coda 1. - http://onecrayon.com/tea/coda/

Comment: I installed the new Zen Coding plugin for Coda (http://befive-design.blogspot.com/2012/12/using-zen-coding-in-panic-coda-2.html) and it still doesn't match tags.

Comment: Nice. Is there a pref to activate tag matching? I still can't get it to do it. :)

Comment: @Joshua Added some more detail.

Comment: works perfectly, incase it helps those key combos are `SHIFT+CONTROL+D`. It will hightlight the entire code block between to tags, for example `<div>content</div>`

Answer (score 2):

Coda 2 still does not include HTML tag matching.  I use Coda 2 myself and Gilbert Pellegrom references the lack of matching in this [blog post quick reviewing Coda 2.](http://gilbert.pellegrom.me/coda-2-quick-review/)

I would echo Peter and email them at coda@panic.com  Maybe with the new release Panic will be even quicker to add requested features.

Comment: yeah I tried dropping a line, unfortunately to no avail. Maybe we can keep requesting and eventually it'll be picked up

Comment: I sent them an email too.  I switched to Sublime 2 because of this. :(

Comment: I need this capability all the time when trying to fix others' HTMessyL. I have installed Github Atom and it does tag matching immediately.